# Can't use wildcards in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard, ls

It is about 3 days I'm struggling with

```
D1="`ls $g???_???_?????$DATE1`"" ` |`""` wc -l`"
       if [ $D1 -eq "0" ]
```

and still it ends with syntax error. 
The last syntax error bash tells is **syntax error at line 1: `|' unexpected**.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). And don't use `ls` like that. To count files: `array=("$g"???_???_?????"$DATE1"); if (( ${#a[@]} == 0 ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked:

```
D1=`ls 'a_costant_string'"$DATE1"????????"$g"* | sort -u | wc -l`
```

I meantion it here because it took me lots of time to find the combination that work correctly and this was actually the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve. However, the pipe symbol is part of a substitution command, and not a substitution command on it's own.

```
D1="`ls $g???_???_?????$DATE1 | wc -l`"
if [ $D1 -eq 0 ]; then
    ...
fi
```